# How can I adjust nth number in a line?

Tags: text-processing, command-line, regular-expression, numeric-data

File contents:

```
RANDOM TEXT    num1=400    num2=15    RANDOM TEXT
RANDOM TEXT    num1=300    num2=10    RANDOM TEXT
RANDOM TEXT    num1=200    num2=5    RANDOM TEXT
```

I would like to subtract 5 for each num2 per line like so:

```
RANDOM TEXT    num1=400    num2=10    RANDOM TEXT
RANDOM TEXT    num1=300    num2=5    RANDOM TEXT
RANDOM TEXT    num1=200    num2=0    RANDOM TEXT
```

Pure bash is preferred, but no biggie if another GNU tool does it better.

Comment: Bash is not a good text editor; would you be satisfied with calling the proper tool *from* bash?

Comment: Are the separators between `RANDOM` and `TEXT` the same as those between the numerical columns, or do you have tab-separated data in which some columns contain spaces?

Comment: In my scenario, I do believe RANDOM TEXT will be consistently 2 columns, but to play it safe, the consistent tell will be num2=

Comment: Is `num2=` column always goes as 4th column?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ($i ~ /num2=/) {sub(/num2=/, "", $i); $i="num2="$i-5; print} } }' file
```

This will loop through each column of each line looking for the column that contains `num2=`.  When it finds that column it will:

1. Remove `num2=` - `sub(/num2=/, "", $i)`
2. Redefine that column as `num2={oldnum-5}` - `$i="num2="$i-5`
3. Print the line - `print`

Comment: In my scenario, I do believe RANDOM TEXT will be consistently 2 columns, but to play it safe, the consistent tell will be num2=

Comment: @TuxForLife: I've updated the answer.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks Jesse

Answer (score 5):

perl:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<=num2=)(\d+)/$1 - 5/e' file
```

To store the contents back into the file:

```
perl -i -pe ...
```

Answer (score 4):

*[Just because I'm trying to become more familiar with [Miller](https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/reference.html) - it requires some jumping through hoops to get the heterogeneous output]*:

```
$ mlr --fs ' ' --repifs --ocsvlite --headerless-csv-output put '
    $num1 = "num1=".$num1; $num2 = "num2=".($num2-5)
' file
RANDOM TEXT num1=400 num2=10 RANDOM TEXT
RANDOM TEXT num1=300 num2=5 RANDOM TEXT
RANDOM TEXT num1=200 num2=0 RANDOM TEXT
```

If the input is actually TSV in which some columns may contain spaces, then

```
$ mlr --fs '\t' --ocsvlite --headerless-csv-output put '
    $num1 = "num1=".$num1; $num2 = "num2=".($num2-5)
' file
RANDOM TEXT num1=400    num2=10 RANDOM TEXT
RANDOM TEXT num1=300    num2=5  RANDOM TEXT
RANDOM TEXT num1=200    num2=0  RANDOM TEXT
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Vim:

```
vim +'g/^/exe "norm! 3Wf=5\<C-A>"' +wq file
```

The first [`+` argument](https://www.vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#-+c) runs a series of normal mode operations on each line to increment the number 5 times. It uses a [`:global`](https://www.vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#:global) command to run this on every line. Simply using [`:normal`](https://www.vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#:normal) with a [range](https://www.vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#cmdline-ranges) `%norm` would be simpler if we weren't using [<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>](https://www.vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#CTRL-A) to increment the number, but in order to (easily) pass this control character into Vim we build the command as a string to run with [`:execute`](https://www.vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#:execute), and thus we need the `:global`.

The second + argument simply [saves the file](https://www.vimhelp.org/editing.txt.html#:wq).

If the format of RANDOM TEXT is less regular (or if you just prefer regular expressions), you could instead use a [`:substitute`](https://www.vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#:substitute) command:

```
vim +'%s/num2=\zs\d\+/\=submatch(0) + 5' +wq file
```

This uses a `:substitute` command to replace the `N` part of `num2=N` with the [existing value](https://www.vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#sub-replace-expression) plus five.